# This stage has no steps Blue ocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I'm creating a Jenkins pipeline using Blue ocean.

Now I try to add a SonarQube analysis to the flow. But when I run the flow it says:

> No steps This stage has no steps

The stage looks like:

```groovy
stage('Analysis') {
      steps {
        script {
          if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop') {
            withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube Server') {
              bat 'mvn sonar:sonar'
              def qualitygate = waitForQualityGate()
              if (qualitygate.status != "OK") {
                error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate coverage failure: ${qualitygate.status}"
              }
            }
          }
        }

      }
    }
```

The flow is running in the develop branch:
[image]
I don't know why Jenkins says this error. can someone help me with this?

Comment: Have you verified `env.BRANCH_NAME == 'develop'`?

Comment: I added a screenshot. It is running in the develop branch.

Comment: `env.BRANCH_NAME` is confusingly not always the actual branch name. _"if corresponding to some kind of change request, the name is generally arbitrary (refer to CHANGE_ID and CHANGE_TARGET)." If this is a pull request, it might be a different name.

Comment: Is there any way to check  on which branch the flow is running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed my flow to use the when keyword:

```
stage('SonarQube analysis') { 
  when {
    branch 'develop'
  }
  steps {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube') { 
      bat 'mvn sonar:sonar'
    }
  }
}
stage("SonarQube Quality Gate") { 
  when {
    branch 'develop'
  }
  steps {
    timeout(time: 10, unit: 'MINUTES') { 
      script {
        sleep 120
        def qg = waitForQualityGate() 
        if (qg.status != 'OK') {
          error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```